# C# reforming a task manager code made with C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

this is C# (Visual Studio 2013) Non of this codes where made from or for me...
hello, I have THIS CODE

```
/* Made by TheDarkJoker94. 
*  Check http://thedarkjoker094.blogspot.com/ for more C# Tutorials 
*  and also SUBSCRIBE to my Youtube Channel http://www.youtube.com/user/TheDarkJoker094 
*  Thanks! */
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics; 

namespace SimpleTaskManager
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        Process[] procs;
        public void GetProcesses()
        {
            procs = Process.GetProcesses();
            if (Convert.ToInt32(label2.Text) != procs.Length) // Check if new processes have been started or terminated
            {
                listBox1.Items.Clear();
                for (int i = 0; i < procs.Length; i++)
                {
                    listBox1.Items.Add(procs[i].ProcessName);  // Add the process name to the listbox
                }
                label2.Text = procs.Length.ToString();
            }
        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GetProcesses();
        }

        // Check every 1 second for changes in the processes list
        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GetProcesses();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            procs[listBox1.SelectedIndex].Kill(); // Kill the process coresponding to the selected index of listbox1 
        }

        private void kIllProcessToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            procs[listBox1.SelectedIndex].Kill();
        }

        public void lsit()
        {
        }

    }
}
```

it works perfectly, but is not EXACTLY what im looking for... I need a code that tells me which is the FOREGROUND window at the moment... so using THIS other code i archived that...

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;

namespace activeWindow
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for Form1.
    /// </summary>
    public class Form1 : System.Windows.Forms.Form
    {

        [ DllImport("user32.dll") ]
        static extern int GetForegroundWindow();

        [ DllImport("user32.dll") ]
        static extern int GetWindowText(int hWnd, StringBuilder text, int count);

        private System.Windows.Forms.Label label1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label label2;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label label3;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label captionWindowLabel;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label IDWindowLabel;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer1;
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components;

        //
        // GetForegroundWindow API 
        //
        private void GetActiveWindow()
        {

            const int nChars = 256;
            int handle = 0;
            StringBuilder Buff = new StringBuilder(nChars);

            handle = GetForegroundWindow();

            if ( GetWindowText(handle, Buff, nChars) > 0 )
            {
                this.captionWindowLabel.Text = Buff.ToString();
                this.IDWindowLabel.Text = handle.ToString();
            }

        }


        public Form1()
        {
            //
            // Required for Windows Form Designer support
            //
            InitializeComponent();

            //
            // TODO: Add any constructor code after InitializeComponent call
            //
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void Dispose( bool disposing )
        {
            if( disposing )
            {
                if (components != null) 
                {
                    components.Dispose();
                }
            }
            base.Dispose( disposing );
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code
        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
            this.label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.label2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.label3 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.captionWindowLabel = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.IDWindowLabel = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.timer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer(this.components);
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // label1
            // 
            this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(136, 8);
            this.label1.Name = "label1";
            this.label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(112, 16);
            this.label1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.label1.Text = "Active Window Detail";
            // 
            // label2
            // 
            this.label2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(16, 40);
            this.label2.Name = "label2";
            this.label2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(96, 16);
            this.label2.TabIndex = 1;
            this.label2.Text = "Window Caption : ";
            // 
            // label3
            // 
            this.label3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(16, 88);
            this.label3.Name = "label3";
            this.label3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(96, 16);
            this.label3.TabIndex = 2;
            this.label3.Text = "Window Handle :";
            // 
            // captionWindowLabel
            // 
            this.captionWindowLabel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(112, 40);
            this.captionWindowLabel.Name = "captionWindowLabel";
            this.captionWindowLabel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(224, 40);
            this.captionWindowLabel.TabIndex = 3;
            // 
            // IDWindowLabel
            // 
            this.IDWindowLabel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(112, 88);
            this.IDWindowLabel.Name = "IDWindowLabel";
            this.IDWindowLabel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 16);
            this.IDWindowLabel.TabIndex = 4;
            // 
            // button1
            // 
            this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(176, 128);
            this.button1.Name = "button1";
            this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(48, 24);
            this.button1.TabIndex = 5;
            this.button1.Text = "EXIT";
            this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
            // 
            // timer1
            // 
            this.timer1.Enabled = true;
            this.timer1.Tick += new System.EventHandler(this.timer1_Tick);
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleBaseSize = new System.Drawing.Size(5, 13);
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(400, 173);
            this.Controls.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.Control[] {
                                                                          this.button1,
                                                                          this.IDWindowLabel,
                                                                          this.captionWindowLabel,
                                                                          this.label3,
                                                                          this.label2,
                                                                          this.label1});
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.StartPosition = System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
            this.Text = "Window Information";
            this.TopMost = true;
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }
        #endregion

        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main() 
        {
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            GetActiveWindow();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

EXPLANATION: The first code gives me the Process name of ALL of the applications that are running at the time... and the second gives me the "WINDOW NAME" and a code... of the application in the foreground.... what I need... is the PROCESS NAME of the FOREGROUND WINDOWS... so as you can see... if i could "mix" the two of them... it will be giving me what i need... ps... i only need the name of the ACTUAL foreground window in a Variable so i can use inside the code.... dont need the windows, boxes o actual text on me desktop... thanks

Comment: I don't know what it is you're asking. You want to combine two strings from what I can gather..

Answer (score 2):

To get the process name of the foreground Window, you have to get the foregound Window `GetForegroundWindow` and then you can get its process id by using `GetWindowThreadProcessId`:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling = true)]
public static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out uint lpdwProcessId);

Process GetActiveProcess()
{
    IntPtr hwnd = GetForegroundWindow();
    uint pid;
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, out pid);
    Process p = Process.GetProcessById((int)pid);
    return p;
}
```

Then you can get the process name:

```
GetActiveProcess().ProcessName
```

Comment: I understand what you are saying... but dont know how to do it :p its been 3 days now going round and round with THIS problem... i think my brain is about to burst D:

Comment: wait.... thats it.... you already did it.... so... that's the WHOLE code?!!!! *.* TESTIIING : D

Comment: it.... sort of works.... but i dont know how to retrive the name... how do i know how to call it or how to do the comparisson to see if the active window's process is the same of my variable "notepad"... from that you wrote... the first part... then i want that IF the foreground window's process is "notepad" or "notepad.exe"(same for me), it make a bip or something that tells me it is actually working :S in short... dont know how to do compare the result with my variable : s

Comment: `if(string.Equals(GetActiveProcess().ProcessName, "notepad", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) {  }`